# Generating useful excel plots with python

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib

Some background: I've used python to perform the data analysis for a research project, and then have used Pyplot to generate the (pretty intricate) figures. However, my partner in the project would like me to export all my plots to excel so he can work with things like line-width and coloring (he will not do these minor graphical tweaks in python, since he cannot program).

Is there an efficient way to turn a Matplotlib plot directly into a plot that can be manipulated in excel? I could take all my data, create a giant numpy array with it, and then export it to a CSV file, which could be opened and manipulated in excel. I don't want to do that since (a) it's a lot of unnecessary work for me, and (b) will end up producing inferior graphs in excel anyway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider using [XLWings](http://xlwings.org/)?

It can directly interface Python to Excel and basically lets you reference Excel worksheets like how VBA does (i.e.: `Range('Sheet1','A10').value`). This would let you use Excel as your front-end to display results (and subsequently plot stuff within Excel) for your Python analysis.

Of course, this doesn't solve the problem of your plots being more complex than what Excel can handle, but it does solve you being able to do the number-crunching in Python and then tweak the presentation of the subsequent results set in Excel.

Disclaimer: I have no relation to XLWings and have yet to use it significantly, but have checked it out and it looks like it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is akin to asking if a cow and tree can mate.

I would suggest either dumping out a vector graphic using either the PS, PDF, or SVG backends. Adobe Illustrator, CorelDraw, and Inkscape (the last one's free, but kinda awkward to use) can load and edit PostScript and SVG files to tweak colors, weights, etc.

Alternatively you could try using [PyGrace](http://pygrace.github.io/) or [graceplot](http://graceplot.sourceforge.net/) in conjunction with XmGrace or QtGrace which you can use to edit graphs later.

You could also convince the unfortunate Excel user to learn Python; it's one of the easier languages. If you do all the data processing beforehand, and provide the (nearly) finished product.

Finally, you could just go with the low-tech iterative option: give the designer print-outs to mark-up, and make the changes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured the answer would be something like this; I learned Python this summer *specifically* so I could stop using excel for data analysis. Unfortunately, the "unfortunate excel" user will not accept the low tech (or even high tech) iterative option (i.e., can you make the lines a hair thinner? Thanks).

Comment: Hello Nick T, I have got kind of question in plot, but no attesntion. I need experts advice.Pease have a look Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248016/how-to-get-more-information-in-2nd-plot-by-clicking-1st-plot-using-python-clicki